# Multiple quotechars when reading a CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to read a CSV that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

s = """
System Name,System ID,System Type,Flood Source,System Authorization,Rehabilitation Program Status,Responsible Organization
"Napa River, left bank above Tulocay Creek","5305000080","Channel","Napa River","USACE Federally constructed, turned over to public sponsor operations and maintenance","Active","USACE - San Francisco District"
"Napa River, right bank below Napa Creek","5305000050","Levee System","","USACE Federally constructed, turned over to public sponsor operations and maintenance","Active","USACE - San Francisco District"
"Needles "S" Street ","3805030008","Levee System",""S" Street Wash, Dead Mountain HA","USACE Federally constructed, turned over to public sponsor operations and maintenance","Inactive","USACE - Los Angeles District"
"Nevada County Levee 1","1905046000","Levee System","Donner Creek","Locally Constructed, Locally Operated and Maintained","Not Enrolled","California"
"Nevada Levee","7005000873","Levee System","","Other Federal Agency","Not Enrolled","Bureau of Reclamation"
"""

pd.read_csv(StringIO(s))
```

The problem is that `"Needles "S" Street "` has multiple quotechars and results in `ParseError`:

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 7 fields in line 5, saw 8
```

I tried [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38592786/multiple-quotechars-in-pandas), but all attempts at writing my own separator end in having a single-column dataframe. Ideas?

Comment: A kludgey thought here though. Since it seems like every non-header row has every field quotes-encapsulated, perhaps you could set the `sep` parameter of your `read_csv()` to `'","'`. You'll still end up with leading and lagging double quotes on your first and last column, but those could be trimmed after they are in the dataframe.

Comment: @JNevill Indeed it's a problem with the data, but there's nothing I can do to fix it at the source. I was thinking this sequence `","` could be interpreted as a separator, but that introduces other issues.

Comment: What if you delete all of the quotes? e.g. `s = s.replace('"', '')`

Comment: @LukaszTracewski What about changing the double quotes at the beginning and end of each line to single quotes.  Then change (",") to (',').  Then split with sep="'" (single quote)?  This would leave the embedded double quotes intact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quotes inside quotes must be escaped with double quotes "" and this line is incorrectly escaped.

```
"Needles "S" Street ","3805030008","Levee System",""S" Street Wash, Dead Mountain HA",...
         ^^^                                       ^^^
```

"S" must be escaped as as ""S"" in two places. The second place has a preceding quote so the entire multi-line string must be quoted with ''' rather than """.

```python
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

s = '''System Name,System ID,System Type,Flood Source,System Authorization,Rehabilitation Program Status,Responsible Organization
"Napa River, left bank above Tulocay Creek","5305000080","Channel","Napa River","USACE Federally constructed, turned over to public sponsor operations and maintenance","Active","USACE - San Francisco District"
"Napa River, right bank below Napa Creek","5305000050","Levee System","","USACE Federally constructed, turned over to public sponsor operations and maintenance","Active","USACE - San Francisco District"
"Needles ""S"" Street ","3805030008","Levee System","""S"" Street Wash, Dead Mountain HA","USACE Federally constructed, turned over to public sponsor operations and maintenance","Inactive","USACE - Los Angeles District"
"Nevada County Levee 1","1905046000","Levee System","Donner Creek","Locally Constructed, Locally Operated and Maintained","Not Enrolled","California"
"Nevada Levee","7005000873","Levee System","","Other Federal Agency","Not Enrolled","Bureau of Reclamation"
'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s))
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                                 System Name  ...        Responsible Organization
0  Napa River, left bank above Tulocay Creek  ...  USACE - San Francisco District
1    Napa River, right bank below Napa Creek  ...  USACE - San Francisco District
2                        Needles "S" Street   ...    USACE - Los Angeles District
3                      Nevada County Levee 1  ...                      California
4                               Nevada Levee  ...           Bureau of Reclamation
```

If you cannot easily fix your data then a quick fix to the data would be to encode all the legal quotes in your data, remove the illegal quotes, then re-quote the data.

```
# 1. replace legal quotes with another symbol to replace back later
s = s.replace('\n"', "\n|").replace('"\n', '|\n')
s = s.replace('",', '|,').replace(',"', ',|')

# 2. remove all illegal quote characters in the data
s = s.replace('"', "")

# 3. re-quote the data
s = s.replace('|', '"')
```

Or do only step 1 and change the quote and delimiter on `pd.read_csv()` call. This will preserve the illegal quotes as-is.

```
s = s.replace('\n"', "\n|").replace('"\n', '|\n')
s = s.replace('",', '|,').replace(',"', ',|')

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
```